# Configure an Avahi reflector to broadcast the address for only certain airplay targets

Tags: avahi, airplay

I'm looking to configure the Avahi daemon in reflector mode (which I have working) to reflect only certain Airplay targets to the other networks. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for an answer for this still, here's a way to forward Airplay and other types of Zeroconf traffic between two Vlans:

In the avahi-daemon.conf, make sure the following is inserted:

```
[reflector]
enable-reflector=yes
```

Next add the following (customizing your Vlans of course):

```
[server]
allow-interfaces=vlan10,vlan20
```

I used two network cards to then bridge the vlans, others have said this could be done with a single card and an allow vlan x-x or allow vlan x, x on the switchport.

Found this solution here: http://www.packetmischief.ca/2012/09/20/airplay-vlans-and-an-open-source-solution/